# BigQuery anti join with lower function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run an anti join with lower function on the joined field.

For example (sample query is nonsense, but it does reproduce the problem):

```
SELECT word FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  where lower(word) not in 
    (select lower(corpus) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare)
```

BigQuery returns an error:

```
Error: Expression on the left side of IN has to be a field. Found LOWER.
```

I couldn't find in documentation anything about such a limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one works...

```
SELECT word,lower(word) as lword 
FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
having lword not in 
(select lower(corpus) from publicdata:samples.shakespeare)
```

There is limitation on using functions in Join. In my experience, BQ compiles "Anti Join" with the same limitations as Join.